# getting 404 error when trying to call servlet from JSP form

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, servlets, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to call a servlet from a jsp using form action, but when I submit the form, a 404 error is displaying. i am using Dynamic Web Module 3.0 and created servlet usning new -> new servlet option of eclipse Oxygen.

[Here is the image of my codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2bS2.png)

[Here is the image of my codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iqatq.png)

[Here is the image of my codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RfL5.png)

[Here is the image of my codes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdGNc.png)

i am used

```
@WebServlet("/UserLogin")
public class UserLogin extends HttpServlet {
    ......
    ...
}
```

to declare my servlet. The servelet is under package databaseFiles.

and code from jsp file is here

in eclipse i can clearly see that eclipse automatically mapped servlet.

```
<form class="w3-container" method="get" action="UserLogin">
</form>
```

and also used

```
action="UserLogin"
action="/UserLogin"
action="/Exam/UserLogin"
```

Here Exam is my project name.

Comment: can't see your servlet code. But i know the scriptlet code you have in index.html is incorrect. You can't call on the request object without first going through a servlet...

Answer (score 0):

i had faced same issue like this, try copying the servlet file in default package and you won't get 404.